# Drawing a frame around a part of a syntactic tree using the `xytree` package

Tags: linguistics, trees, xy-pic

I am trying to make a box around a part of a syntactic tree, using the `xytree` package. I am aware that we can do it, using the `qtree` package which has the `\qframesubtree` command. But, I would like to do it, using the `xytree` package. Can anyone tell me how?

Below is what I have for now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xytree}

\begin{document}


\Tree [.S \qroof{John}.NP [.VP V\\loves \qroof{Mary}.NP ] !{\qframesubtree} ]


\xytree{& \xynode[-1,1]{S} \\
\xytrinode{NP} && \xynode[-1,1]{VP} \\
\xynode{John} & \xynode[0]{V} && \xytrinode{NP}\\
& \xynode{loves} && \xynode{Mary} 
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure why anyone would really want to use `xytree` for trees, given the existence of tree drawing packages like `tikz-qtree` and `forest`, but it's possible to do what you want using `xypic` `\save` and `\restore` along with object composition. Unpacking the code somewhat:

```
 \save"2,2"*+<2.5em,1.5em>{}."4,4"*+=[F-]\frm{}\restore
```

We first compose node `"2,2"` (plus enough room to include the `loves` node) with node `"4,4"`, and then add a frame `[F-]\frm{}` to it. This is done within `\save` and `\restore` which maintains the previous positions of the nodes, effectively allowing an overlay.

I've also shown how to do this with `forest` in case you are interested...

```
% !TEX TS-program = LaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xytree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\qtreecenterfalse
Qtree
\Tree [.S \qroof{John}.NP [.VP V\\loves \qroof{Mary}.NP ] !{\qframesubtree} ]

XYtree
\xytree{
& \xynode[-1,1]{S} \\
\xytrinode{NP} && \xynode[-1,1]{VP} \\
\xynode{John} & \xynode[0]{V} && \xytrinode{NP}\\
& \xynode{loves} && \xynode{Mary}
\save"2,2"*+<2.5em,1.5em>{}."4,4"*+=[F-]\frm{}\restore  
}

Forest
\begin{forest}
[S [NP [{John},roof ]] [VP,tikz={\node[draw,fit to=tree]{};} [V\\loves] [NP, [{Mary},roof] ]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful!